# JFace dialog wrong width

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I uses the JFace dialog in my app. And I don't subclass the getInitialSize(xxx). The JFace could determine the correctly height of dialog, But width. My question is if the JFace dialog could auto calculates my dialog size without a static initial size? I could adjust the static size to fix my screen(MAC OS X). But in other platform(WINDOWS), it become a bad size.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the layout data properly for all the widgets, then the dialog should size properly. You can also try to do a shell.pack(), to ensure the widgets & dialog get the right size